# mssql-jdbc can not save BigDecimal fields. Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I see an error, when trying to persist object with BigDecimal.

*com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal*

to avoid this error I must to decrease BigDecimal accuracy. Or just use JTDS driver.

Maybe, I do not understand something? This error persists for years. Is there some property to set up, while using mssql-jdbc?

Answer (score 1):

http://dertompson.com/2008/01/03/bigdecimal-and-jdbc-since-java-5-0-2/

Apparently the conversion process converts the double to a string that may contain too many values behind the decimal. That is then converted to the BigDecimal. This conversion process is where the error comes from.

I solved this by using decimalFormat() to retain the number of significant digits I wanted and using that string in the new BigDecimal() conversion.

Comment: Yes, I know that tale of woe. But I was surprised that in 2017 there is still no solution (unless the manual scaling).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link - need to use scale functionality so that you can round the decimal

[How to insert into SQL Server decimal column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089927/how-to-insert-into-sql-server-decimal-column)